# Parent element does not close after deleting an element: XML Twig

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I'm trying to find an element with an attribute with a certain value and removing it from the document.

In this example I'm looking for a File element, with an attribute called "RelativePath" whose value is "....\TS\ETestScenario.inc".

The Problem: The last element - `</Files>` is missing after I run the script. Also, the 'VisualStudioProject' closing tag is printed twice. Not sure what im doing worng here.

```
use strict;
use XML::Twig;
my $fileName = 'Z:\autotest\test.xml';
my $t= new XML::Twig( TwigRoots=> 
            { Files => \&upd_files_section
             },

              twig_print_outside_roots => 1,               # print the rest
              keep_spaces => 1,
              keep_atts_order=>1,
            );              

$t->parsefile("$fileName");
#$t->parsefile_inplace ("$fileName");


sub upd_files_section{
    my ($t, $inputFields)=@_;

    my $file_to_delete = $inputFields->get_xpath("./File[\@att='..\..\TS\ETestScenario.inc']");
    $inputFields->delete($file_to_delete);
    $t->flush;
}
```

Incorrect XML Output:

```
<VisualStudioProject
    ProjectType="Visual C++"
    Version="8.00"
    Name="xxx"
    ProjectGUID="{}"
    RootNamespace="xx"
    SccProjectName="x"
    SccLocalPath="."
    SccProvider="x"
    >
        <Files>
                <Filter Name="Source Files" Filter="cpp;bat">
                        <File RelativePath="..\..\TS\ADK_MacCommon_Test.cpp">
                        </File>
                        <File RelativePath="..\..\FSO\EADK.cpp">
                        </File>
                <Filter Filter="ico;cur;bmp;dlg;rc2;rct;bin;rgs;gif;jpg;jpeg;jpe" Name="Resource Files">
                </Filter>
                <File RelativePath="..\..\TS\ETestScenario.inc">
                </File>
        </VisualStudioProject>
        <Globals>
        </Globals>
</VisualStudioProject>
```

Comment: Remove the `flush` or replace it with `purge`.

Comment: Either your perl script and your xml have errors. Fix them if you wait for better answers.

Comment: I've updated the code to where it compiles now. The XML is incorrect that that's my issue. The solution from mirod below works like a charm.THANKS!! but as far as escaping the back slashes goes, I thought I would not have to since the string is within single quotes.

Comment: it's not!It is in double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, the XML is not valid, and the code doesn't compile.

That said if I understand correctly, I think the handler should be:

```
sub upd_files_section{
    my ($t, $inputFields)=@_;
    my @files_to_delete = $inputFields->get_xpath("./File[\@RelativePath='..\\..\\TS\\ETestScenario.inc']");
    foreach my $file (@files_to_delete) { $file->delete; }
    $t->flush;
}
```

A few notes:

- you need to escape the backslashes in the XPath expression, or Perl thinks they're there to escape the following character; alternatively, use simple quotes or `q{}` around the expression: `q{./File[@RelativePath='..\..\TS\ETestScenario.inc']}`
- in the XPath expression, it should be `@RelativePath`, not `@att`
- `get_xpath` returns a list of elements, which you have to delete
- to delete an element call `delete` on it, no need to go through its parent like with the DOM
- you could also cut all the children at once by using the... `cut_children` method: `$inputFields->cut_children( q{File[@RelativePath='..\..\TS\ETestScenario.inc']});`